# Setting Routes for RestApi in Yii2

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am trying to make rest api with my methods.

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => ['ApiController'],
        'patterns' => [
            'PUT,PATCH api/{id}/update' => 'update',
            'DELETE api/{id}/delete' => 'delete',
            'GET,HEAD api/{id}' => 'get',
            'POST api/{id}/create' => 'create',
            'GET,HEAD' => 'api/index',
            '{id}' => 'options',
            '' => 'options',
        ]
    ],
```

Api controller:

```
/**
 * Displays homepage.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    //  $id = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam("id"); //
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return "ok";

}

/**
 * Displays homepage.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function actionGet($id)
{
    // $id = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam("id"); //
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return "get";
}
```

Url `api` returns index action, but url `api/1` doesn't return get action.

How to configure routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with the default actions provided by `yii` you can simplify your code quite a bit to make it work.

1. Configure the response type on the application configuration, then you won't need to do it in each method.
2. Remove the `'patterns'` element from your rules, `yii` automatically matches the patterns that you are trying to use.
3. Decide if you want to pluralize your rules or not, if you don't want to pluralize them you need to add `'pluralize' => false` to your configuration rules.

> `web.config`

```
// configure json response globally
'response' => [
    'format' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
    'formatters' => [
        Response::FORMAT_JSON => [
            'class' => '\yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter',
            'prettyPrint' => YII_DEBUG,
            'encodeOptions' => JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE,
        ]
    ],
],

// Add ApiController rules
'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => 'api',
        // uncoment the next line if you want to request '/api/2' instead of '/apis/2'
        // 'pluralize' => false
    ],
    // ... more rules here
]
```

> `ApiController`

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\Controller;

class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return 'Api index action';
    }

    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return "Get item $id";
    }
}
```

Using the configuration provided you can request the `index` route sending a `GET` request to the `/apis` endpoint, to control the result customize `actionIndex`, you can provide a `dataProvider` as the response and the formatter element will deal with it correctly.

To request *one* element of the collection, send a `GET` request to the `/apis/5` endpoint, where `5` is just an example `$id`, if you return a model, the formatter will deal with it using the `fields` attribute of the model.

If you want to use endpoints like in your question, i.e. without the plural form, uncomment the `pluralize` line on the example, the endpoints will be `/api` and `/api/5`.

There are multiple examples of this on the official documentation, the [quick start](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start) and [building a REST API](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/748/building-a-rest-api-in-yii2-0) pages make for some good reading and are packed with examples.

Personally I would recommend not naming a controller `ApiController`, it seems confusing, your API probably has `api` already on the `url` so you will end up with `urls` like `https://api.mydomain.com/api/5`